# Dynamic and dependent form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to make a dynamic and dependent form for a booking script.
In the first input field the date and time will be filled in by the customer.
In the second part of the form, there is an dropdown, which will provide the available (unbooked) rooms.

```
<form name="booking" action="<? echo $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>">
  <input type="date" name="pref_date">
  <input type="time" name="starttime">
  <input type="time" name="endtime">
  <select name="available-rooms">
     <? $sql="SELECT rooms 
              FROM bookings 
              WHERE (pref_date=pref_date)
              AND (start_time < starttime AND end_time > endtime)"; // UNTESTED

        $result=mysql_query($sql,$db);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) { ?>
        <option value="<? echo $id; ?>"><? echo $room; ?></option>
        <? } ?>

  </select>
  <input type="text" value="name">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I think this has to be done with AJAX or Jquery... but how can I make this happen?
Does anyone have some tutorial which I can learn which does the similar, or does anyone have some time to help me with this?

The code as shown above is minified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX if you want your page to react to user input using information that is only available to the server. The way you do it in vanilla javascript is by creating an XMLHttpRequest object (which is implemented in every modern broswer), sending a request to the server and then listening for the answer, when you get it you can update the  options accordingly.

Simple demo

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "getbookings.php", true);
//You can send information here to the $_GET or $_POST variable in php
xhttp.send("I love hotels");

//And to listen to the answer
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

the onreadystatechange event triggers when the state of the request changes and 4 means it has finished. A status different from 200 means that something has gone wrong in the server, so remember to check for that! As to what the php file should do, just print out a plain text or JSON string with the information you need so that it can be parsed by javascript.

You can read more at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp

Comment: As an addendum, newer browsers also can support the Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is the successor (eventually!) to XMLHttpRequest.